# const reference function parameter: Is it possible to disallow temporary objects?

Tags: c++, constants, pass-by-reference, temporary-objects

It it possible to have a function parameter that enforces the following semantics:

The parameter will not be altered by the function.
Calling the function never creates copy or temporary object for the parameter.

Example:

```
void f(const std::string & str);
```

Interface tells clients that the parameter will not be altered, and if the parameter is already of type std::string, no copy is created.

But it is still possible to call this as

```
const char * hello = "hello";
f(hello);
```

which creates a temporary std::string object before the function f is entered and destroys it again after exit from f.

Is it possible to disallow this, either with a different function declaration, or by (hypothetically) altering std::string implementation.

Comment: Sounds like XY problem to me. One of the beauty of the language is that automatic temporary creation and binding. Why do you want to disallow this? If you care about possible performance hit due to constructor called, it should not be the problem of API provider, but a problem of a caller. Practical solution for `std::string` is to use `std::string_view` or homebrew solution.

Comment: Had to look up what xy-problem means. No I do not think so. Agree it would be the client's responsibility. But that's also me and I am curious if I can make sure that I do not make a mistake in my calls. And std::string is just used as an example here. Not particularly interested in std::string. A nice thing is I learned something new about =delete.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm going to start from the end here.

> or by (hypothetically) altering `std::string` implementation

Don't do this, for fear of nasal demons. Seriously, don't. Let the standard library behave in a standard fashion.

> Is it possible to disallow this, either with a different function declaration

Another declaration is just the ticket, as a matter of fact. Add an overload that accepts an r-value reference, and define it as deleted:

```
void f(std::string && str) = delete;
```

Overload resolution will pick it for temporaries, and the deleted definition will cause an error. Your intended function can now only be called with l-values.

Comment: std::string is just an example that everyone knows, and I agree that I do not want to alter that. Interesting with the delete keyword, I have to try that. I was only aware of deleting default constructors and the like in this way.

Comment: @LudwigSchulze - You can provide a deleted definition for any function. That much easier to make overload resolution go boom when you want to prevent something :)

Comment: I feel that after trying this, I might have a followup question for cases with ~5 parameters, where ~3 parameters have this semantic. Would be a new question, of course.